# React Navigation Reset on Nested Navigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack, react-navigation-v5

I am using React-Navigation v 5.0.1, I have a Drawer navigator nested inside Stack navigator that looks like this:

***MainStack.js***

```
function MainStack() {
 return(
    <Stack.Navigator>
          <Stack.Screen name="Splash" component={Splash} />
          <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={Login} />
          <Stack.Screen name="HomeDrawerStack" component={HomeDrawerStack} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
 )
}
```

***HomeDrawerStack.js***

```
function HomeDrawerStack() {
 return (
    <Drawer.Navigator>
       <Drawer.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
    </Drawer.Navigator>
 )
}
```

When I tap a logout button on **Home** screen, how do I navigate to **Login** screen and reset / clear all other screens? *(so it triggers the componentWillUnmount on other screens)*

Answer (score 0):

This code will navigate to Login Screen after clearing the stack. so that back button or back swipe will not work to navigate to `HomeDrawerStack`

```
navigation.reset({
    index: 0,
    routes: [{ name: "Login" }],
});
```

Comment: I tried this and it doesn't reset to Login screen, it resets back to Home screen

Answer (score -2):

if I share how I handled it, it is like, I am sharing my code snippet as png here, so what I have done is appended Navigator with redux, and I use to change my stack or replace my stack by dispatching event to store attached to Navigator.

[image]